# ssas 2005 cube marked as unprocessed after being processed by sql server job SQL Server Analysis Services Command

Tags: ssas

I have a SSAS 2005 cube deployed. There is a SQL Server 2005 job running nightly using SQL Server Analysis Services Command like below. The job runs no problem. But after each run, I saw the cube properties in SSMS became'unprocessed'. But the 'Last processed' is the finished date and time of the job, which means the job did processed the cube. A deploy from the BIDS will bring the cube to processed status. But when the job finishes, the cube became 'unprocessed'. Any idea why the cube is marked as unprocessed by the job?

```
        <Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
          <Parallel>
            <!--################# Dimensinos ################-->

            <!--Branch-->
            <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
              <Object>
                <DatabaseID>RMIS_cube</DatabaseID>
                <DimensionID>Vw Dim Retail Branch</DimensionID>
              </Object>
              <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
              <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
            </Process>

            <!--Products-->
            <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
              <Object>
                <DatabaseID>RMIS_cube</DatabaseID>
                <DimensionID>Vw Dim Products</DimensionID>
              </Object>
              <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
              <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
            </Process>

            <!--Time-->
            <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
              <Object>
                <DatabaseID>RMIS_cube</DatabaseID>
                <DimensionID>Vw Dim Time</DimensionID>
              </Object>
              <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
              <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
            </Process>

            <!--################# Facts ################-->

            <!--Sales-->
            <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
              <Object>
                <DatabaseID>RMIS_cube</DatabaseID>
                <CubeID>Rmis</CubeID>
                <MeasureGroupID>Vw Fact Sales</MeasureGroupID>
                <PartitionID>Vw Fact Sales</PartitionID>
              </Object>
              <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
              <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
            </Process>

          </Parallel>
        </Batch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the script does not process all partitions contained in the cube. One way to find out what part of the cube is not processed is as follows:

- In BIDS or Management Studio, right-click the cube, select "Process"
- Set "Process Options" to "Process Default"
- Click on the button "Impact Analysis"
- A dialog pops up which in the bottom lists the objects that are unprocessed.

Comment: Yes I added new facts in BIDS and deployed the project but didn't add the new facts in the script of the job. Now I run the job the cube is not 'unprocessed', but the last processed date is not the finishing date of the job either.